# Can office web apps be installed on server 2016?

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, office-web-apps

The only documentation I've come across mentions the latest version supported is Server 2012 R2.

Even Office Online for SharePoint 2016 says to install this on Server 2012 R2.

> Supported operating systems for Office Online Server
>
> You can run Office Online Server on the following operating systems:
>
> - The 64-bitedition of Windows Server 2012 R2

Can Office Web Apps be installed on Server 2016 or even 2014?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not been able to install this on Server 2016, as it requires .net framework 4.5.  And you cannot install fw 4.5 on Server 2016, as far as I can tell.  [image: Setup Error on Server 2016]

Answer (score 0):

Office Online server still not certified/supported on windows server 2016. We contact many times, everytime same answer we are working on it.

I would record the voice on this forum...https://office.uservoice.com

Answer (score 0):

The November 2016 release of OOS will install properly on Windows Server 2016 and appears to function as normal, that said, it isn't supported as of yet. The next release of OOS should support it, I would imagine.